# Javascript - Checkbox onclick-+ operations

Tags: javascript

i'm working on a project and try to do something with checkboxes.

when a user click to a checked checkbox total value is - reverse is +

this is my code. i use recal function to do that check box is checked and send it to js as true

```
 echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='check1' value='".$info['eventCategory']."'  onclick='recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",true)' checked></td><td>" . $info['id'] . "      " . $info['name'] . "</td>";




function recal(val,sum)
{ 
    if(sum)
    {
    var total = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
    total+=val;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;
   }       
}
</script>
```

when sum is come as true it doesnt not sum the value :S

Answer (score 1):

looks to me like a type casting problem - change this line:

```
var total = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
```

to this:

```
var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML, 10);
```

Comment: is this wrong = if(check1.checked){onclick='recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",true)'}

Comment: id use jquery for that: something like: `$('#check1').on('change',function(){recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",true);});` - you might need to add this attribute to teh checkbox itself: `<input type=checkbox name='check1' id='check1' value....`

Comment: onclick=if(this.checked){'recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",true)'} what is wrong with that

Comment: if it works, then nothing is wrong with it. id just personally use jquery because im more familiar with it and you can do more with less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Also try looking at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FaQQU/) it should give You more overview what could've go wrong.